# Do any of the other classes of beings lack gross bodies?

Tags: gods, philosophy, vedanta, asuras, body

I heard on this site that the Devas lack gross bodies, and only have causal and subtle bodies. If this is true, does this mean that some other classes of beings, for example, Asuras, lack them as well?

Comment: No because the scriptures describe asuras as having bodies, having sex, raising children, etc.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Does that mean that devas also possess gross bodies?

Comment: I would imagine so.

Comment: @Ikshvaku I targeted my question at those who do not believe devas have gross bodies, however.

Comment: Downvote trolls go away

Answer (score 1):

Composition logistics of a body acquired by Linga shareera in a Para loka ,solely depends on, what is true for that loka, furthermore it would differ from  earthy gross body (made of Panchikrtha Panchaboothas) .

Scriptures may only give  a cue on such matters however, it may not detail the anatomy of such a body.

Shiva Gita ( Shiva Rama Samvaada), Upanishads suggest that Linga shareera do acquire bodies other than human in paraloka.

Jiva is free from embodiment, / acquisition of body(by Linga shareera), only upon attaining Bramhaloka,by Arcirādimārga.

BrahmaSutra Pada 4

> **Adhikarana IV: (Sutras 8-9)** The soul which has attained the Saguna Brahman,  effects its desires be mere will.
> **Adhikarana V: (Sutras 10-14)A released soul which has attained Brahmaloka can exist with or without a body according to its liking**.
> **Adhikarana VI: (Sutras 15-16)** The released soul which has attained the Saguna Brahman can animate several bodies at the same time.
> **Adhikarana VII: (Sutras 17-22)** The released soul which has attained Brahmaloka has all the lordly powers except the power of creation, etc. There is no return to this world for these released souls.
> Courtesy Swami Sivananda

Shiva Gita Chapter 11(Translation P K Sundaram)

[image]

---

---

[image]

**PS :**

Your question is `Do any of the other classes of beings lack gross bodies?`
Scriptures say(afaik), Without an aquisition of a phenomenal body of a kind , befitting that paraloka,  there aren't any experiences for a mere Linga shareera (blue print) which would be otherwise latent ..

Only upon attaintment of brahmaloka, a jiva may choose to be free from the aquisition of a body ,not prior to that.

Asuras (asuṣu indriyeṣu ramante iti asurāḥ) besides being nonchalant about dharma,  are those who always want to revel in joy of senses only..There could be a variety of gradation of Asuras attaining range of paraloka gathis.Puranas and other scriptures, may only give a cue on them broadly , using pseudo statements(paribhasha) , owing to the fact  they are beyond the realm of senses..So the anatomy of such bodies  are inexplicable.Visible spectrum of light(the range of wavelengths that human eye can detect) , rods and cones in retina and  many other factors , influence the perception of color . For eg. It is said that a dog many not be able to perceive grass green . So every perception is subjective , and is constrained to the locus of this phenomenal world .

Some higher beings could also be mind born , unlike humans( jarayuja,)  are said to aquire a body as that of light (but don't ask color shape etc . I don't know)..

Those who perform rituals devoid of inclusive meditation like Agnihotra ,Darsapurnamasa(also for those who have followed dharma / indulged in social welfare), reach chandraloka , thru path of smoke , there they aquire a body as that  of water particles..

Sinners acquire a Yathana deha suitable to experience punishments (in due).

Comparison of Para Loka Gathis interms of Joy is can be found in [Br up 4.3.33](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc120049.html)

> Human joy multiplied a hundred times makes one unit of joy for the Manes..
> Which multiplied by 100 times is a unit of godhead by their actions.,(manushya gandharva) x100= 1 unit of gods by birth(deva gandharva) ,followed by Indra brahaspati prajapati and so on.

A jiva can escape the uncontrollable predicament  and such limitations , only by uplifting its quality of consciousness.

Comment: How does this apply to classes of beings like Asuras? Do they have gross bodies?

Comment: Also, what are the bodies that those in paraloka have like? Do they have color and shape? Or are they colorless and shapeless?

Comment: @TerjijKassal , updated in ans.

Comment: Is it possible that these bodies have no color or shape at all?